# Java NTP Implementation

Tags: java, ntp

I have a server/client application and I need to synchronize the time of the clients with the time of the server. Thereby I need to implement an NTP Server (or similar) on the server application and an NTP client on the client side.

NTP is not a requirement, but it has to be accurate for at least 50ms (then it would be already a bit critical, but still usable, until I figure out a better solution).

Does anyone have any advices, if there is a good implementation that could help me, or if it's doable to implement this by myself (with the desired precision).

#### Edit: More information about the project

The server application runs on a customers Home PC. The computer of the customer does *not* have to change the time, only the client (which is running on a dedicated computer, running on Ubuntu).

This is an IoT project, there are many clients that are very small hardwar devices and should have the same date/time as the server. Because the client won't fiddle with the client's configuration, and he does not have access to it (it's a blackbox), I can run my application using admin rights, if needed.

I don't want to install an NTP Server on my client's home PC. This is the reason I want to deliver this functionality inside of my Java Application.

Comment: Why not just use regular ntpd?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch my clients wont have connection to the internet, it has to be a local synchronization of the time between the client and the server. (I don't know if the implementation you are relating to can do this)

Comment: As long as the client can connect to the server a local ntpd could do that; I don't think you'll be able to set the system clock from Java (and even if you could, I don't think you'll get the precision you want).

Comment: The problem is that this is a consumer product and I can't tell the customer to install a NTP Server on his PC. This is the reason I want to do it inside of my application. Imagine, you would install iTunes and they would say, you can only use it if you install an NTP Server.

Comment: And does iTunes require the clock on your iPhone and your mac be synced +/- 50ms?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is right; you should just tell the customer to install ntpd. You can't set the system clock in Java. Moreover, even if you could do so, it would require admin privileges.

Comment: No, there is a big difference though. The client hardware is dedicated for this application (as opposed to the server application, which runs on the customers home PC). The time of the customers PC does not have to change, only the time on the client (i.e. on the dedicated PC running the client software). Dedicated PC means, it will ONLY run the client software (on Ubuntu). Maybe, I will edit the question to make this more clear. @fge Admin rights on the client is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a NtpClient in apache commons-net that you can use for this. You can use this to figure out the clock drift at least of your client pc and try to compensate for that.